# Blender- How to make a 2D object 3D without bevel?

Tags: 3d, 2d, blender

Okay, so here's my problem, I want to make Apple's logo 3D in Blender, and what I have is a 2D model of their logo. What I want to do is sort of copy the model around a center point and then join the outside vertices? Hopefully there is an easy way to do this, cause I don't really want to do it by hand. Think of the problem as making a circle a sphere, or making a rectangle a cylinder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a circle a sphere or a rectangle a cylinder, I'd use the spin feature.

See: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Duplicating/Spin

Note, Apple's logo doesn't lend itself that well to a spin operation though.

If I were trying this, I would probably take the left half of the logo and spin that to get something vaguely apple shaped to start with.  You could then modify it by hand to make it look a bit more like a real Apple.

Then, I would make a cylinder that matched the bite in the apple, and subtract that from my 3d apple to match the logo.

For the leaf on top, I would probably bevel it instead of trying to do a spin.

BTW, this probably would have been better posted to https://blender.stackexchange.com/